# cleaner way to install Apache, MySql and PHP on windows

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, integration

I really say its a very hard time for me when started to install these 3 things on my windows 7 platform. I know there is WAMP available to install at one shot. But I for good understanding I want to install these 3 separately and want to integrate it. Why its so clumsy and difficult for integration? Can anybody please advise me how I can do the following?

1. Which latest versions of these 3 are best compatible?
2. After installing Apache what in which mode I should run it? Console application or Server Mode?
3. In apache whats the difference if I run with CGI or without CGI?
4. What the things or modules or any changes I have to ensure before going to install the MySql and PHP?
5. When I installed the MySql it tell me that MySql server is installed. Is the my MySql server is another HTTP server? Is it a replacement for Apache?
6. After I install the PHP what are the minimum things I should check so that I will be ensured that it will work with Apache after integration.
7. I found the logfile locations for Apache. But where can I find the logfile locations for PHP and MySql?

May be I am newbie in this domain so I am asking these questions. But it will help anyone who want to start newly. Please advise me...

Comment: I think you should break this down into multiple questions. Answering all of these question together in sufficient detail would be a hell of a lot of work. Tackle each topic one by one.

Comment: Also, make some effort to do some research yourself before asking SO … question 5 in particular should be answerable by the results page itself of a one word Google query.

Comment: No offence, but I think someone who doesn't know that MySQL is not a replacement for Apache shouldn't be trying to manually install all this stuff.  Seriously, stick with MAMP or XAMPP

Comment: I know its a very senseless question. But please someone answer my questions and then close.

Comment: If you're so fixed on seperate installations and managing libraries seperately... why are you using windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I still dont see why you dont want to just install a package like WAMPP/XAMPP or Zend Server CE (personal favourite atm).

Put it this way:

1. Generally speaking, all latest versions are compatible, meaning,
   latest PHP + latest MySQL + latest Apache
2. Typically server mode, but this really depends on what you want...
   this is not something for noobs, again rather use a package
3. Do you want CGI? or not? Read the documentation on
   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/howto/cgi.html
4. Dont bother, this usually isn't necessary - again use a package
5. Mysql is a Database Service
6. Browse to http://localhost/ if it works, then it works. Libraries depend on your personal needs, if you for example need php's
   MCRYPT library installed, you'll know - install it... if it's
   already installed, it will work anyway
7. Google it

I doubt this will help you much...